# Functions within classes in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I am trying to place a function that was made in a class inside a dictionary but keep getting the error 'name 'eggs' is not defined. This is what i have tried so far,

```
class spam(object):
    def __init__(self,my_dict={'eggs',eggs}):
        self.my_dict=my_dict
    def eggs(self):
        print('eggs')
```

I have also tried using outside the class

```
class spam(object):
    def __init__(self,my_dict):
        self.my_dict=my_dict
    def eggs(self):
        print('eggs')

my_dict={'eggs':eggs}
```

I have also tried replacing that dictionary with:

```
{'eggs':eggs()}
{'eggs':spam.eggs}
{'eggs':spam.eggs()}
```

Can someone either tell me how to create this dictionary or another way to call this function based on a string input.

Comment: what are you up to exactly? Are you sure `__int__` is the name you're after and not `__init__`? Still why create a dictionary holding the functions? That's what classes essentially do, they have a `__dict__` that holds this information.

Comment: That was a mistake, i used __init__ in the actual code

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an *instance* of the class to access that function. You can do this outside the class:

```
{'eggs':spam().eggs}
```

Comment: Thats not the solution to the question. It does not solve the NameError.

Comment: @NiklasR, no `NameError` is raised when I run this in Python 3.6

Comment: It will still give a `NameError` when OP tries to use this variable as default value in `def __init__(self, my_dict=eggs)`

Answer (score 1):

Outside the class, `eggs` is a non-static class-method, so you can't access it without a class instance like

```
{'eggs': spam().eggs}
```

You may consider static-ing it, if you want to, using

```
@staticmethod
def eggs ():
    print('eggs')
```

So stuff like `{'eggs': spam.eggs}` would work.

Comment: I think it works only from python 3.5 or 3.6. Still `NameError: name 'spam' is not defined`

Comment: No, you were right. It failed on 3.5. Order of method creation

Comment: you have to edit your post to explain that it only works on python 3.6 then. ATM only Niklas R answer works for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Create the dictionary inside `__init__()`.

```
class spam(object):
  def __init__(self, my_dict=None):
    if my_dict is None:
      my_dict = {'eggs': self.eggs}
    self.my_dict = my_dict
```

If you want to store the original method and not the bound instance method, use `spam.eggs` or `type(self).eggs` (both having slightly different semantics).